# Create document in view row. Two and more form documents inline in view

Tags: forms, view, xpages, document, lotus-domino

I type a text in inline form, and do not close inline form, after that I create top main document by top form. Inline form which not closed move up in row which just created main document row. But it must stay in old place. How fix it? Or how to create 2 or more documents by inline form in view when forms all have a text?

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xp:view xmlns:xp="http://www.ibm.com/xsp/core"
    xmlns:xe="http://www.ibm.com/xsp/coreex"
    xmlns:xc="http://www.ibm.com/xsp/custom">
    <xp:this.beforePageLoad><![CDATA[#{javascript:var documentId : String = context.getUrlParameter('documentId');
if (documentId!="") {sessionScope.put("Channal",documentId)};
if (!sessionScope.containsKey("Channal")) {
var docChannal : NotesDocument = database.getView("subChannal").getDocumentByKey("True");
if (docChannal != null) {
sessionScope.put("Channal",docChannal.getUniversalID());
}
}}]]></xp:this.beforePageLoad>
    <xp:panel id="Main">
        <xp:this.rendered><![CDATA[#{javascript:try {
var docChannal : NotesDocument = database.getDocumentByUNID(sessionScope.get("Channal"));
return docChannal.getUniversalID()!=""
} catch(e) {
    return false
}}]]></xp:this.rendered>
        <xp:panel id="documentMessageCreate">
            <xp:this.data>
                <xp:dominoDocument var="documentMessageCreate"
                    formName="Message" computeWithForm="onsave" action="newDocument"
                    scope="request" ignoreRequestParams="true">
                    <xp:this.postNewDocument>
                        <xp:actionGroup>
                            <xp:this.condition><![CDATA[#{javascript:return currentDocument.isNewNote() && currentDocument.isResponse()}]]></xp:this.condition>
                            <xp:modifyField name="Read"
                                var="currentDocument">
                                <xp:this.value><![CDATA[#{javascript:database.getDocumentByUNID(currentDocument.getParentId()).getItemValue("Read")}]]></xp:this.value>
                            </xp:modifyField>
                        </xp:actionGroup>
                    </xp:this.postNewDocument>
                    <xp:this.parentId><![CDATA[#{javascript:sessionScope.get("Channal") }]]></xp:this.parentId>
                </xp:dominoDocument>
            </xp:this.data>
            <xp:this.rendered><![CDATA[#{javascript:var docChannal : NotesDocument = database.getDocumentByUNID(sessionScope.get("Channal"));
return ! @IsNotMember(@UserName() ,docChannal.getItemValue("MessageCreate"))  || docChannal.getItemValueString("MessageCreate")==""
/* var docChannal : NotesDocument = database.getDocumentByUNID(sessionScope.get("Channal"));
var ArrayName=[];
ArrayName=ArrayName.concat('[Manager]');
ArrayName=ArrayName.concat('[Administrator]');
return ! ( @IsNotMember(database.queryAccessRoles(@UserName()),ArrayName) && @IsNotMember(@UserName() ,docChannal.getItemValue("MessageCreate")) ) || docChannal.getItemValueString("MessageCreate")==""
*/}]]></xp:this.rendered>
            <xp:table style="width:100%" id="tableMessage"
                styleClass="messageCreate">
                <xp:tr>
                    <xp:td valign="top" style="width:32px">
                    </xp:td>
                    <xp:td>
                        <xp:inputRichText
                            value="#{documentMessageCreate.Body}" id="MainMessage">
                            <xp:this.dojoAttributes>
                                <xp:dojoAttribute
                                    name="autoGrow_minHeight" value="50">
                                </xp:dojoAttribute>
                            </xp:this.dojoAttributes>
                        </xp:inputRichText>
                    </xp:td>
                </xp:tr>
                <xp:tr>
                    <xp:td></xp:td>
                    <xp:td>
                        <xp:button
                            value="#{javascript:translateString('Send')}"
                            id="CreateMessage">
                        <xp:eventHandler event="onclick" submit="true" refreshMode="partial" refreshId="Main">
                            <xp:this.action>
                                <xp:actionGroup>
                                <xp:saveDocument
                                        var="documentMessageCreate">
                                    </xp:saveDocument>
                                                <xp:executeScript>
                                        <xp:this.script><![CDATA[#{javascript://context.redirectToPage("Main")
getComponent("MainMessage").setValue("")
}]]></xp:this.script>
                                    </xp:executeScript>
                                </xp:actionGroup>
                            </xp:this.action></xp:eventHandler></xp:button>
                    </xp:td>
                </xp:tr>
            </xp:table>
        </xp:panel>
        <xp:panel id="dataViewMessage">
            <xp:this.data>
                <xp:dominoView var="viewMessage"
                    viewName="(xpMessage)">
                    <xp:this.parentId><![CDATA[#{javascript:sessionScope.get("Channal") 

}]]></xp:this.parentId>
                </xp:dominoView>
            </xp:this.data>
            <xp:repeat rows="10" var="row" value="#{viewMessage}"
                id="viewRepeatMessage">
                <xp:panel id="documentMessage">
                    <xp:this.data>
                        <xp:dominoDocument var="documentMessage"
                            action="openDocument" documentId="#{javascript:row.getNoteID()}"
                            ignoreRequestParams="true" formName="Message" scope="request">
                        </xp:dominoDocument>
                    </xp:this.data>
                    <xp:table id="tableData">
                        <xp:this.style><![CDATA[#{javascript:if (row.getColumnIndentLevel()>0) {
 return "width:100%;margin-left:"+(row.getColumnIndentLevel()*32).toString()+"px;"
  }  else {
   return "width:100%;"
  }
 }]]></xp:this.style>
                        <xp:this.styleClass><![CDATA[#{javascript:if (row.getColumnIndentLevel()==0) {
return "message" }}]]></xp:this.styleClass>
                        <xp:tr>
                            <xp:td rowspan="3" style="width:32px"
                                valign="top">
                            </xp:td>
                            <xp:td>
                                <xp:text escape="true"
                                    style="font-size:8pt;font-family:Arial;color:rgb(128,128,128);margin-right:10.0px"
                                    id="dataAuthor">
                                    <xp:this.converter>
                                        <xp:convertDateTime
                                            type="date">
                                        </xp:convertDateTime>
                                    </xp:this.converter>
                                    <xp:this.value><![CDATA[#{javascript:var document : NotesDocument = row.getDocument();
return @Name('[CN]',document.getItemValue('Author'))}]]></xp:this.value>
                                </xp:text>
                                <xp:text id="dataCreated"
                                    style="font-size:8pt;color:rgb(128,128,128)">
                                    <xp:this.value><![CDATA[#{javascript:try{
    var document : NotesDocument = row.getDocument();
    var date : NotesDateTime = document.getItemValue('Created' )[0];
    var Today:NotesDateTime = session.createDateTime("Today");
    Today.setNow();
    if ( (Today.timeDifference(date) / 86400).toFixed(0) != 0) 
        {return date.toJavaDate()}
    else
        {return translateString('Today') +'  '+ @LeftBack(date.getTimeOnly(),6)}
} catch (e){}}]]></xp:this.value>
                                    <xp:this.converter>
                                        <xp:convertDateTime
                                            pattern="dd.MM.yyyy HH.mm">
                                        </xp:convertDateTime>
                                    </xp:this.converter>
                                </xp:text>
                            </xp:td>
                        </xp:tr>
                        <xp:tr>
                            <xp:td rowspan="2" valign="top">
                                <xp:text escape="false" id="messageBody"
                                    value="#{documentMessage.Body}">
                                </xp:text>
                            </xp:td>
                        </xp:tr>
                        <xp:tr>
                        </xp:tr>
                        <xp:tr>
                            <xp:td></xp:td>
                            <xp:td>
                            <xp:link
                                    text="#{javascript:translateString('CreateResponse')}"
                                    id="MessageResponse" style="font-size:8pt;margin-right:10.0px"
                                    escape="true">
                                    <xp:this.rendered><![CDATA[#{javascript:var docChannal : NotesDocument = database.getDocumentByUNID(sessionScope.get("Channal"));
return ! @IsNotMember(@UserName() ,docChannal.getItemValue("MessageReplyCreate"))  || docChannal.getItemValueString("MessageReplyCreate")==""}]]></xp:this.rendered>
                                    <xp:eventHandler event="onclick"
                                        submit="true" refreshMode="partial"
                                        refreshId="inPlaceFormMessageResponse" id="eventHandler1">
                                        <xp:this.action>
                                            <xp:actionGroup
                                                condition="#{javascript:true //!viewScope.containsKey('Response')}">
                                                <xp:executeScript>
                                                    <xp:this.script><![CDATA[#{javascript:   
     viewScope.put('Response',row.getNoteID());
     var c = getComponent("inPlaceFormMessageResponse");
c.toggle()
}]]></xp:this.script>
                                                </xp:executeScript>
                                            </xp:actionGroup>
                                        </xp:this.action>
                                    </xp:eventHandler>
                                </xp:link>
                            </xp:td>
                        </xp:tr>
                    </xp:table>
                    <xe:inPlaceForm id="inPlaceFormMessageResponse"
                        partialEvents="true">
                        <xp:panel>
                            <xp:this.data>
                                <xp:dominoDocument
                                    var="documentMessageResponseCreate" formName="Message"
                                    parentId="#{javascript:row.getNoteID()}"
                                    computeWithForm="onsave" scope="view">
                                <xp:this.postNewDocument>
                                        <xp:actionGroup>
                                            <xp:this.condition><![CDATA[#{javascript:return currentDocument.isNewNote() && currentDocument.isResponse()}]]></xp:this.condition>
                                            <xp:modifyField name="Read"
                                                var="currentDocument">
                                                <xp:this.value><![CDATA[#{javascript:database.getDocumentByID(currentDocument.getParentId()).getItemValue("Read")}]]></xp:this.value>
                                            </xp:modifyField>
                                        </xp:actionGroup>
                                    </xp:this.postNewDocument>
                                </xp:dominoDocument>
                            </xp:this.data>
                            <xp:table id="table2">
                                <xp:this.style><![CDATA[#{javascript:"width: calc(100% - "+(row.getColumnIndentLevel()*32+32).toString()+"px); margin-left:"+(row.getColumnIndentLevel()*32+32).toString()+"px;"}]]></xp:this.style>
                                <xp:tr>
                                    <xp:td>
                                        <xp:inputRichText
                                            id="inputRichText1"
                                            value="#{documentMessageResponseCreate.Body}">
                                            <xp:this.dojoAttributes>
                                                <xp:dojoAttribute
                                                    name="autoGrow_minHeight" value="50">
                                                </xp:dojoAttribute>
                                            </xp:this.dojoAttributes>
                                        </xp:inputRichText>
                                    </xp:td>
                                </xp:tr>
                                <xp:tr>
                                    <xp:td>
                                        <xp:button
                                            value="#{javascript:translateString('Send')}"
                                            id="CreateMessageResponse" style="margin-right:10.0px">
                                            <xp:eventHandler
                                                event="onclick" submit="true" refreshMode="partial"
                                                id="eventHandler3" refreshId="viewRepeatMessage">
                                                <xp:this.action>
                                                    <xp:actionGroup>
                                                        <xp:saveDocument
                                                            var="documentMessageResponseCreate">
                                                        </xp:saveDocument>
                                                        <xp:executeScript>
                                                            <xp:this.script><![CDATA[#{javascript:var Agent : NotesAgent;
var NoteID : string;
var AgentName : string;
AgentName = '(CreateEvent'+currentDocument.getDocument().getItemValueString('Form')+'Create)';
NoteID = currentDocument.getNoteID();
    Agent = database.getAgent(AgentName);
    if(Agent != null){
      Agent.runOnServer(NoteID);      
    }
}]]></xp:this.script>
                                                        </xp:executeScript>
                                                        <xp:executeScript>
                                                            <xp:this.script><![CDATA[#{javascript:viewScope.remove('Response');
database.getView("(xpMessage)").refresh();
var c = getComponent("inPlaceFormMessageResponse")
c.hide()
}]]></xp:this.script>
                                                        </xp:executeScript>
                                                    </xp:actionGroup>
                                                </xp:this.action>
                                            </xp:eventHandler>
                                        </xp:button>
                                    </xp:td>
                                </xp:tr>
                            </xp:table>
                        </xp:panel>
                    </xe:inPlaceForm>
                </xp:panel>
            </xp:repeat>
            <xp:div style="text-align:center">
                <xe:pagerAddRows id="pagerAddRowsMessage"
                    text="#{javascript:translateString('ShowMore')}"
                    disabledFormat="hide" refreshPage="true" for="viewRepeatMessage">
                </xe:pagerAddRows>
            </xp:div>
        </xp:panel>
    </xp:panel>
</xp:view>
```

Thanks for any help!

**Create response forms with a text** 
[image]

---

**Save Main Form. InLine form response with text "1-resp=1" move Up and stay under just created Main doc (not under doc with text "1")**
[image]

---

**Save 1-resp=1**
[image]

---

Comment: Could you add a screenshot of the UI how it is supposed to look like?

Comment: screenshots added

Comment: May be some code will refresh Inpalce Form like refreshPage="true"  in  <xe:pagerAddRows id="pagerAddRowsMessage" text="ShowMore" for="viewRepeatMessage" refreshPage="true"></xe:pagerAddRows>